# Getting CORS error rather than expected 429 response when rate limit is reached

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core, axios, cors

In my backend I implemented an IpRateLimit middleware with the AspNetCoreRateLimit package in my .net core entity framework backend. When an IP Address x makes y calls in a specific time, it gets blocked for a certain time and the backend should return an 429 error and this works fine when testing with postman. But when the I make an request with axios, that is supposed to get blocked because of the ip rate limiter, I receive an axios error:

```
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44372/api/Users/Login/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
"POST https://localhost:44372/api/Users/Login/ net::ERR_FAILED"
```

After receiving this error, I have added the needed header, but it hasn't changed the result. Other axios requests to my backend (also post, put and delete) work fine, but when the ip rate limiter hits, I just get the cors error.

I implemented the limiter in my application as in the following tutorial:
https://edi.wang/post/2019/6/16/ip-rate-limit-for-aspnet-core

React axios request:

```
 async function buildPostAndFetch(url, param, header) {
            const finalurl = `${BASE_URL}${url}`;
            return axios.post(finalurl, param, {headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}})
            .then(res => {
                response(res);
                return res.data ? res.data : true;
            })
            .catch(err => {              
                handleError(err);
                return false;
            })        
    }

handleError() {
 const handleError = err => {
        setError(true);
   
        if(err.request?.status === 0) {
            console.log("*********************************************")
            console.log(err.request);
            console.log("*********************************************")
            // throw new Error("API is currently offline or you are not connected to the internet:(");
        } else if(err.response.status === 429) {
            console.log("*********************************************")
            console.log(err.response);
            console.log("*********************************************")
        }
    }
}
```

When requestion and limiter hits I always get in the err.request.status === 0 path.

Comment: you should using nginx to proxy your request to the same ip:port to avoid CROS limit, like axios -> nginx -> server @Niklas

Comment: Can you please explain this more detailed to me? I don't want to avoid a limit, but I don't understand, why I receive an CORS error, instead of the configured 429 error code

Comment: why you recieve CROS? because send request port is from 3000 to 44372, you should send 3000 to 3000, how to solve? I my project, I am forward the request by nginx @Niklas

Comment: Limit rate recieved CROS error is wired, It should return 429 if you fix CROS by add header. @Niklas

Comment: Which header should I add. All the other requests work without letting frontend and backend run on the same port. I have configured CORS in my backend as the following:

Comment: app.UseCors(options =>
            options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());

Comment: Most server systems/runtimes by default don’t add application-set headers to 4xx and 5xx responses but instead only add them to 2xx success responses and maybe to 3xx redirects. So you may need to do explicit config to force headers to get added to 4xx responses, so that 429 response ends up with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. In Apache and nginx for example, that’s done by adding the `always` keyword to the header-setting directive. Maybe your server system has some similar thing.  But the reason you get a CORS error is, that 429 response lacks the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: Thank you for all this information, I understand the problem now. No its clear why it is working with postman, because I read that postman doesn't needs an Acess-Control-Allow-Origin header. Please post the comment as Answer in order to tag it as solution.

Comment: I had the same issue, and the problem was because I was adding the IpRateLimiting middleware before the CORS middleware. IpRateLimiting needs to be after adding the CORS middleware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most server systems/runtimes by default don’t add application-set headers to `4xx` and `5xx` responses but instead only add them to `2xx` success responses and maybe to `3xx` redirects.

So you may need to do explicit config to force headers to get added to 4xx responses, in order for that `429` response end up with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

In Apache and nginx for example, that’s done by adding the `always` keyword to the header-setting directive. Maybe your server system has some similar thing.

You get a CORS error because that `429` error has no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: Where would you configure this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure that you have `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` from NuGet.

Then, please add the following to your `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Put it before AddMvc() if there's any
    services.AddCors();
}
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Put it before UseMvc() if there's any
    app.UseCors(
        options => options
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
    );

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

After finish the above configuration, by inspecting on your network tab (Browser's developer tools) you may see the one of the returned response header is `access-control-allow-origin : http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: I have tried this, but it has changed nothing. I think that the error have to come from my frontend, because making this requests and getting the 429 error, when it's supposed, works fine when using postman

Comment: I had the same issue, and the problem was because I was adding the IpRateLimiting middleware before the CORS middleware. IpRateLimiting needs to be after adding the CORS middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same error. Im my case the problem was in the wrong order of my middleware components in `Startup.Configure` pipeline. My `RateLimit` middleware was placed before `UseCors` component, so it was short-circued request before it could reach the `cors` middleware. Therefore no cors header in response.

Correct older should be:

```
public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            //.... other middleware

            app.UseRouting();

            //....

            app.UseCors("YourPolicyName");
            app.UseMiddleware<RequestRateLimitMiddleware>();

            //....
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            //....
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
app.UseCors(opt => opt
    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000"")
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod());
```

The protocol (http/https) can not be omitted. Also, the cors middleware should be placed after `app.UseRouting` but before `UseAuthorization`.

You can see [Middleware Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#middleware-order) .

Comment: Please add a explanation